# How to wire this to Levinton IPS02

Tags: wiring, lighting

[image][image][image]

I have been trying to wire this to a motion sensor switch, but after turn back on the power, the sensor is blinking, but the lights won’t turn on.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What was there? How was it connected to the wires? How are you  wiring the new Leviton?

Comment: Does the manual pushpad not turn the lights on either?

Comment: The manual push pad didn’t turn on the light.

Comment: I plug the hot wire to the BK screws, the other black wire to the purple.

Comment: Did you connect a wire to the screw marked RD?

Comment: Yes, I did connect the line (which is the other black wire) to RD

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks squarely into the back of the box please?